# Meteor: Authenticating Chrome Extension via DDP

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth, meteor, ddp

I've built a Chrome Extension that takes a selection of text and when I right click and choose the context menu item, it sends that text to my Meteor app. This works fine, however, I can't figure out the process of using Oauth to authenticate users.

I'm using this package: https://github.com/eddflrs/meteor-ddp

Here is the JS within background.js (for Chrome Extension):

```
var ddp = new MeteorDdp("ws://localhost:3000/websocket");

    ddp.connect().then(function() {
        ddp.subscribe("textSnippets");

        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
            ddp.call('transferSnippet', ['snippetContent', 'tag', snippetString]);
        });
    });
```

Here is the relevant portion of my other JS file within my Chrome Extension:

```
function genericOnClick(info) {
    snippetString = [];
    snippetString.push(info.selectionText);
    var snippetTag = prompt('tag this thing')
    snippetString.push(snippetTag);

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(snippetString);
}
```

And here is the relevant portion of my Meteor app:

```
'transferSnippet': function(field1, field2, value1, value2) {
    var quickObject = {};
    quickObject.field1 = value1[0];
    quickObject.field2 = value1[1];

    TextSnippets.insert({
        snippetContent: value1[0],
        tag: value1[1]
    });

}
```

Basically I'm stuck and don't know how to go about making a DDP call that will talk to my Meteor app in order to authenticate a user

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, but if anyone is still looking for a solution. I had a similar problem that I was able to solve using the following plugin: https://github.com/mondora/asteroid. Here is an example of how to do it for twitter oauth:
https://github.com/mondora/asteroid/issues/41#issuecomment-72334353